# Change display orientation on ILI9325

Tags: arm, display, tft

I've started to play with a cheap TFT display, called HY28B. It's pretty well known, I guess...
Anyway, I want to change the orientation of the display to landscape mode, but somehow it doesn't do what I want.

I tried to config the display with this configuration (ILI9325): http://henningkarlsen.com/electronics/library.php?id=51

And I changed the Entry mode (0x03) register value to 0x10B0, but my string is still appaer in portrait mode. I draw the string with the display's sample code from ebay.

This is the exact config what I'm using:

```
  LCD_WriteReg(0xE5, 0x78F0); // set SRAM internal timing
    LCD_WriteReg(0x01, 0x0100); // set Driver Output Control  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x02, 0x0700); // set 1 line inversion  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x03, 0x1030); // set GRAM write direction and BGR=1.  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x04, 0x0000); // Resize register  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x08, 0x0207); // set the back porch and front porch  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x09, 0x0000); // set non-display area refresh cycle ISC[3:0]  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x0A, 0x0000); // FMARK function  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x0C, 0x0000); // RGB interface setting  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x0D, 0x0000); // Frame marker Position  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x0F, 0x0000); // RGB interface polarity  
    //*************Power On sequence ****************//  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x10, 0x0000); // SAP, BT[3:0], AP, DSTB, SLP, STB  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x11, 0x0007); // DC1[2:0], DC0[2:0], VC[2:0]  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x12, 0x0000); // VREG1OUT voltage  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x13, 0x0000); // VDV[4:0] for VCOM amplitude  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x07, 0x0001);  
    delay(200); // Dis-charge capacitor power voltage  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x10, 0x1090); // SAP, BT[3:0], AP, DSTB, SLP, STB  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x11, 0x0227); // Set DC1[2:0], DC0[2:0], VC[2:0]  
    delay(50); // Delay 50ms  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x12, 0x001F); // 0012  
    delay(50); // Delay 50ms  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x13, 0x1500); // VDV[4:0] for VCOM amplitude  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x29, 0x0027); // 04  VCM[5:0] for VCOMH  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x2B, 0x000D); // Set Frame Rate  
    delay(50); // Delay 50ms  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x20, 0x0000); // GRAM horizontal Address  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x21, 0x0000); // GRAM Vertical Address  
    // ----------- Adjust the Gamma Curve ----------//  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x30, 0x0000);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x31, 0x0707);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x32, 0x0307);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x35, 0x0200);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x36, 0x0008);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x37, 0x0004);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x38, 0x0000);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x39, 0x0707);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x3C, 0x0002);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x3D, 0x1D04);  
    //------------------ Set GRAM area ---------------//  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x50, 0x0000); // Horizontal GRAM Start Address  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x51, 0x00EF); // Horizontal GRAM End Address  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x52, 0x0000); // Vertical GRAM Start Address  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x53, 0x013F); // Vertical GRAM Start Address  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x60, 0xA700); // Gate Scan Line  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x61, 0x0001); // NDL,VLE, REV   
    LCD_WriteReg(0x6A, 0x0000); // set scrolling line  
    //-------------- Partial Display Control ---------//  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x80, 0x0000);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x81, 0x0000);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x82, 0x0000);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x83, 0x0000);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x84, 0x0000);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x85, 0x0000);  
    //-------------- Panel Control -------------------//  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x90, 0x0010);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x92, 0x0600);  
    LCD_WriteReg(0x07, 0x0133); // 262K color and display ON
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: To all reading, the OP may need more help with the datasheet than I can give below, it's a good starting point, but I have no time to read up and down the sheet to see what's going on. See comments on this answer if you think you can help.

---

### Original Post:

---

You set register 3 to the value: 0x1030 in your code. Now see the Adafruit datasheet of your chipset (I'm not the biggest Ada supporter in existence, but it's the only link I could find that's close to proper English):

[Adafruit ILI9325 Chip Datas](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/ILI9325.pdf)

On Page 55 of 107, it shows a table. You want AM = 1 and ID[0:1] are your choice depending on whether you want up/down and mirrored/unmirrored.

Now scroll up to page 54, to show the register layout:

```
{...}{D7} {D6} {D5} {D4} {D3} {D2} {D1} {D0}
{...}{ORG}{0}  {ID1}{ID0}{AM} {0}  {0}  {0}
```

As you can see, your last 0 writes a 0 to AM, you want the last cipher to be 8 for vertical, thus: 0x10?8, where ? is your choice based on the directions in the table on page 55.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I've just tried this, but if I change the register value to LCD_WriteReg(0x03, 0x10B8);
I only see the background color, nothing else, unfortunately.

Comment: Btw, I need AM to be 0, because that's for the landscape view as I see.

Comment: @erbal It's possible I got the orientation wrong, but as the original string was making your text, as you say "portait mode" it is not unlikely the other setting is the other mode. This data sheet, as many from the site are, is ambiguously worded and at some points not quite accurate, so probably all information should be taken with a grain of salt. For example: You now set the ORG bit, which was not set in your original code, but I don't feel like reading the entire datasheet on my only day off to find out what that description exactly intends to specify. First try: turn that back off.

Comment: I tried a lot of combinations, with ORG bit set and reset but it doesn't work somehow.

Comment: @erbal I'm afraid I can't quite come up with anything else. I just read the datasheet concerning the register that points directly at what you're trying to do. These little issues are often what pops up in 'cheap stuff', after all if all was fully tested and documented like a TI/AMD/Analog chip it'd be exactly as 'expensive' as one. As I'm currently quite high-powered in the day-to-day this isn't really the time for me to read 107 pages of it and see if enough of it makes sense. This is left to you or another with more time I'm afraid.

Comment: @erbal added an edit to see if it catches some attention to the comments. Hope that helps as well. It might be a Contrast setting somewhere as well. You could check that in the datahseet.